# Best practice for null-checking in Scala

Tags: scala

I understand that `null` is frowned upon in Scala, and that one should always wrap optional values within an `Option` (or a "null type" if one is available).

The advantages are clear, there should never be a need to check against `null` values, and the resulting code is both safer and more pleasant to read.

In practice however, nothing prevents a value from being `null` - the rule is not enforced by the compiler and is more of a gentleman's agreement. This can easily break when interacting with Java APIs, for example.

Is there a best-practice for this? Say, for example, that I need to write an `Url` case class, and that instances of this class can be created from a `java.net.URI`:

```
object Url {
  def apply(uri: URI): Url = Url(uri.getScheme, uri.getHost, uri.getRawPath)
}

case class Url(protocol: String, host: String, path: String) {
  def protocol(value: String): Url = copy(protocol = value)
  def host(value: String): Url = copy(host = value)
  def path(value: String): Url = copy(path = value)
}
```

An `URI` instance can return `null` for `getScheme`, `getHost` and `getRawPath`. Is it considered sufficient to protect against these in the `apply(URI)` method (with `require` statements, for example)? Technically, in order to be entirely safe, it'd be better to protect the `protocol`, `host` and `path` helper methods, as well as the constructor, but that sounds like an awful lot of work and boilerplate.

Is it considered safe, instead, to protect against APIs known to accept / return `null` values (`URI` in our example) and to assume that external callers will either not pass `null` values or only have themselves to blame if they do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When dealing with pure functions, it is always better to stick to total implementations and instead of using `null`, `require` or exception throwing, to encode all failures in data. The types like `Option` and `Either` are there exactly for that. Both of them are monads, so you can use the "for"-syntax to with them.

The following modification to your code shows a total function `apply`, which only produces a meaningful value, when the input Java `URI` provides no `null`s. We encode the notion of "meaningful" by wrapping the result in `Option`.

```
object Url {
  def apply(uri: java.net.URI): Option[Url] =
    for {
      protocol <- Option(uri.getScheme)
      host <- Option(uri.getHost)
      path <- Option(uri.getRawPath)
    }
    yield Url(protocol, host, path)
}

case class Url(protocol: String, host: String, path: String)
```

The function `Option` is a standard null-checking function, which maps `null` to `None` and wraps values in `Some`.

---

Concerning your "setting" functions, you can implement `null`-checking in them similarly, using `Option`. E.g.:

```
case class Url(protocol: String, host: String, path: String) {
  def protocol(value: String): Option[Url] = 
    Option(value).map(v => copy(protocol = v))
  // so on...
}
```

However I would advice against that. In Scala it is conventional to never use `null`s, so it is as well conventional to only implement `null`-handling for "bridge" APIs, when you get values from Java libs. That's why the `null`-checking does make perfect sense when converting from `java.net.URI`, but after that you are in Scala world, where there should be no `null`s, and hence `null`-checking simply becomes redundant.

Comment: Worth mentioning that `nullCheck` is just the `Option` *object* in Scala.

Comment: Thanks, your point is a good one and I understand it. I feel that it does not address protecting the helper `protocol`, `host` and `path` methods, though, or am I missing something? Should I just consider that callers will never pass `null`?

Comment: What do you mean that is not protecting them? None of them can ever become `null`.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan Thanks for your correction. I totally forgot about that.

Comment: @goral how about `url.copy(protocol = null)`, or even `Url(null, null, null)` ?

Comment: It cannot end with this because `protocol <- Option(uri.getScheme)` will yield either `Some(scheme)` or `None`.

Comment: Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @goral Nicolas was talking about the setting functions. E.g., see `def protocol` in the question.

Comment: I don't know if it has a name but I kind of love that companion-validation-object pattern. It looks very neat, now I'm looking for some place to use it ;)