# Failing in a companion object's apply mehod

Tags: scala

It's common for Scala classes to have `apply` and `unapply` methods in their companion object.

The behaviour of `unapply` is unambiguous: if its parameter is or can be transformed into a valid instance of the class, return a `Some` of it. Otherwise, return `None`.

To take a concrete example, let's imagine a `Url` case class:

```
object Url {
  def apply(str: String): Url = ??? 
  def unapply(str: String): Option[Url] = ???
}

case class Url(protocol: String, host: String, path: String)
```

If `str` is a valid URL, then `unapply` will return a `Some[Url]`, otherwise `None`.

`apply` is a bit less clear to me, however: how should it react to `str` not being a valid URL?

Coming from the Java world, my first instinct is to throw an `IllegalArgumentException`, which would allow us to implement the companion object as:

```
object Url {
  def apply(str: String): Url = ... // some function that parses a URI and throws if it fails.

  def unapply(str: String): Option[Url] = Try(apply(str)).toOption
}
```

I understand that this is not considered terribly good practice in the functional world (as explained, for example, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23992051/best-practice-for-null-checking-in-scala#23992790)).

The alternative would be to have `apply` return an `Option[Url]`, in which case it'd be a simple clone of `unapply` and better left unimplemented.

Is that the correct conclusion to reach? Should this type of potentially failing `apply` methods simply not be implemented? Is throwing, in this case, considered to be ok? Is there a third option that I'm not seeing?

Comment: The unapply signature should be `def unapply(url: Url): Option[String]`. The purpose of `unapply` is to extract the parameters that build the `Url` object.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. You're 100% correct and just made me realise I didn't understand `unapply` at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bit subjective, but I don't think you should do either.

Suppose you allow `apply` to fail, i.e. throw an exception or return an empty option. Then doing `val url = Url(someString)` might fail, despite looking awfully like a constructor. That's the whole problem: the `apply` method of a companion object should reliably construct new instances for you, and you simply cannot reliably construct `Url` instances from arbitrary Strings. So don't do that.

`unapply` should generally be used to take a valid `Url` object and return another representation with which you could create a `Url` again. As an example of this, look at the generated `unapply` method for case classes, which simply returns a tuple containing the arguments with which it was constructed. So the signature should actually be `def unapply(url: Url): String`.

So my conclusion is that *neither* should be used for the construction of a `Url`. I think it would be the most idiomatic to have a method `def parse(str: String): Option[Url]` to make explicit what you're actually doing (parsing the string) and that it might fail. You can then do `Url.parse(someString).map(url => ...)` to use your `Url` instance.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. I have the exact same question for implicit conversions - transforming an string to a url is such a common operation, but I guess the same answer applies. The policy is to create a new question for this though, isn't it?

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo I guess so, but I can already tell you that it's probably not wise to do implicit conversions if you cannot reliably make the conversion!

Answer (score 3):

It's typically the responsibility of the user of the extractor to decide how to handle failure in the case of `None`, and the pattern matching syntax makes this reasonably convenient. Here's a slightly simpler example:

```
import scala.util.Try

object IntString {
  def unapply(s: String) = Try(s.toInt).toOption
}
```

Now we can write any of the following:

```
def intStringEither(s: String): Either[String, Int] = s match {
  case IntString(i) => Right(i)
  case invalid => Left(invalid)
}
```

Or:

```
def intStringOption(s: String): Option[Int] = s match {
  case IntString(i) => Some(i)
  case _ => None
} // ...or equivalently just `= IntString.unapply(s)`.
```

Or:

```
def intStringCustomException(s: String): Int = s match {
  case IntString(i) => i
  case invalid => throw MyCustomParseFailure(invalid)
}
```

This flexibility is one of the nice things about unextractors, and if you're throwing (non-fatal) exceptions in the `unapply` you're short-circuiting that flexibility.

Comment: As usual, your answers are great - this one explains something I didn't know I had not understood until now. I'm accepting @DCKing's answer as I feel it's a better fit for the actual question, but wish I could accept yours for "question I did not know I had".